# Mysql error with time range from subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I need to check the start and end times to have the time available for scheduling. But it produces an error when I include both the start and end time columns.

```
SELECT horariosfixos 
FROM agendamento_horarios 
WHERE horariosfixos NOT IN(SELECT horaInicio,horaFim 
                           FROM agendamento 
                           WHERE data = '17-10-2016' 
                           ORDER BY horaInicio ASC)
```

> Error: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT horariosfixos 
FROM agendamento_horarios 
WHERE horariosfixos NOT IN(SELECT horaInicio 
                           FROM agendamento 
                           WHERE data = '17-10-2016' 
                           UNION 
                           SELECT horaFim as horaInicio
                           FROM agendamento 
                           WHERE data = '17-10-2016')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ah.horariosfixos
    FROM  agendamento_horarios AS ah
    LEFT JOIN  agendamento AS a  ON a.data = '17-10-2016'
      AND  (      ah.horariosfixos = a.horaInicio
              OR  ah.horariosfixos = a.horaFim 
           )
    WHERE  a.id IS NULL
    ORDER BY  ah.horaInicio ASC
```

`LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is a better way to say `NOT IN`, at least in this case.

Both columns can be gotten by the same reach into agendamento.